# Número de tarjeta de crédito con PHP

Tags: php

Necesito capturar los ultimos 4 digitos de la tarjeta de credito y guardar estos en una variable. ¿Cómo puedo obtener solo esos últimos 4 dígitos con `PHP`?
A momento obtengo el numero de la tarjeta de la siguiente forma:

```
$tarjeta = Tools::getValue('card_number');
```

Comment: ¿Has probado la función subsrt()?

Comment: Deberías agregar el código de lo que has intentado

Comment: `substr("1234 5678 9012 3456", -4);` devuelve _3456_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checa la documentación oficial de PHP

[function.substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

```
<?php
  $rest = substr("abcdef", -1);    // devuelve "f"
  $rest = substr("abcdef", -2);    // devuelve "ef"
  $rest = substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // devuelve "d"
?>
```

;)

Answer (score -1):

Intenta probar esta función a ver qué tal:

```
function getLast4Numbers($credit_num){
    return str_replace(range(0,9), "*", substr($credit_num, 0, -4)) .  substr($credit_num, -4);
}
```